# How to get the real file name in kernel module

Tags: c, filenames, kernel-module, printk

I'm creating a kernel module that intercept the unlink command and make a copy of the file that want to be unlinked. For now, I intercept the unlink command and im trying to print the path of the file but it doesn't work right.

I have a method that receive a `char *path` parameter and I use printk to show the path, but this print some rare strings like "\xe07l\xd3\xf"

```
asmlinkage int hacked_sys_unlink(const char *pathname)
{
    printk("RM_CATCHED: unlink( \"%s\" )\n", pathname);
    return original_sys_unlink(pathname);
}
```

When I unlink some file and use dmesg command i get this:

```
[ 1531.847856] RM_CATCHED: unlink( "`g\xcfYMV" )
[ 1531.848071] RM_CATCHED: unlink( "\xe07l\xd3\xf" )
[ 1534.851623] RM_CATCHED: unlink( "\xe07l\xd3\xf" )
[ 1534.852091] RM_CATCHED: unlink( "" )
[ 1541.861962] RM_CATCHED: unlink( "" )
```

How can I get the real path of the file like `/path/to/file.txt`?

Comment: I guess you need to fetch the filename in the same manner as the [original unlink system call](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/namei.c#L4106)

Answer (score 1):

The core reason of getting rubbish printed instead of a nice real file name is that first you need to copy the string from user space into kernel space. Usually `copy_from_user()` function is used for that. In this case you have a NULL-terminated string, and there's a variation of that function called `strncpy_from_user()` which can be used instead.

To make things easier, it's best to follow what the original function does. It calls `getname()` function which eventually calls `strncpy_from_user` among lots of other things it does to get the name reliably. Call this function, and it will get you the file name that is passed in the system call.

Answer (score -1):

Your pointer here:

```
current_pt_regs()->di;
```

Example:

```
printk("%s\n", (char *)current_pt_regs()->di);
```

Comment: "This isn't even wrong", c.f. with Aleksey's answer.